# Possible to change Windows UI language to Spanish while keeping English keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, language

I need to change my Windows (10) UI language from English to Spanish, however this changes the shortcut keys for most Windows apps (e.g. Notepad, Office, Explorer...), which for me is impossible to get used to.

For example: ctrl+S for save becomes ctrl+G for guardar in Spanish.

Is there any way to use Spanish as UI language while simultaneously using English Windows keyboard shortcuts for Windows apps?

Thanks!

Comment: Some keyboard shortcuts are system-wide but most are app specific. The one you mention seems to be from an app and it is expected to change depending on the language the app is using

Comment: Thanks for the input. Indeed, apps in the current state have different keyboard shortcuts, some having changed to Spanish (seemingly all Windows apps except Edge) while others remain in English (mostly 3rd party apps). 

I should clarify that the apps I'm looking to change the keyboard shortcuts for are Windows apps (e.g. Notepad, Office, Explorer etc.).

Comment: Then I'm afraid that's how it is. Probably you won't be able o change any shortcuts unless the software itself has that configuration option and they rarely do.

Comment: That's a shame. Guess the only option then is to use a work-around like the Autohotkey app and manually change all hotkeys in affected apps.